# Any viscosity solution must be the distance function?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Suppose $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is open and bounded. Is it possible anybody could supply a simple proof that any viscosity solution of$$\begin{cases} |Du| = 1 & \text{in }U \\ u = 0 & \text{on }\mathbb{R}^d \setminus U,\end{cases}$$must be the distance function?

**Thoughts.** We want to convert the representation formula $u(x) = \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus U} |x - y|$ into two families of test functions that constrain the viscosity solution from above and below.

Comment: Could you please include the definition of the viscosity solution you are using?

Comment: What do you mean by simple? I suppose you do not want to use uniqueness of viscosity solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a homework problem, so let me just give a hint. Let $u$ be a viscosity solution of the eikonal equation you wrote. Consider the test function $\phi(x)=L|x-y|$ for fixed $y \in \partial U$. Use the viscosity subsolution property to show that when $L>1$, $u-\phi$ has a global maximum at $y$. Continue the proof from here to show that $u$ is less than the distance function. Then do something similar to show the opposite inequality.